# Select form from multiple forms in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

Using Jquery change(), how can I select just form1 fields instead of just all form fields? Here's my code below. Right now its detecting changes for the fields of both forms, however I only want it to detect changes in fields in form1.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<label for="textfield"></label>
<input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" />
<label for="select"></label>
<select name="select" id="select">
<option value="yes">yes</option>
<option value="no">no</option>
</select>
</form>

<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="">
<label for="textfield2"></label>
<input type="text" name="textfield2" id="textfield2" />
<label for="select2"></label>
<select name="select2" id="select2">
<option value="yes">yes</option>
<option value="no">no</option>
</select>
</form>

<script>
$(':input').change(function() {
        alert('Handler for .change() called.');
        }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

to detect only change events from form1:

```
$('#form1 :input').change(function() {
   alert('Handler for .change() called.');
});
```

to do the same for form2 you'd have to change it to

```
$('#form2 :input').change(function() {...
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/escusado/nVxFh/

'change' event bubbles so you can catch it at a container level:

```
$('#form1').change(function(){
  $('#console').text('te');
  //change actions
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class specific to your form 1 stuff and refer to that

```
<form class="form1sel" id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<label for="textfield"></label>
<input class="form1sel" type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" />
<label for="select"></label>
<select class="form1sel" name="select" id="select">
<option value="yes">yes</option>
<option value="no">no</option>
</select>
</form>

<script>
$('.form1sel').change(function() {
    alert('Handler for .change() called.');
}); 
</script>
```

or just use a more specific selector

```
<script>
$('#form1 :input').change(function() {
    alert('Handler for .change() called.');
}); 
</script>
```